# Container que se ajusta a 100% de altura e largura do tamanho da janela

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, viewport

Eu queria criar um `container` ou uma `secção` que se ajuste automaticamente ao tamanho da altura e largura da tela, que mesmo quando redimensionada a `secção` se adapte ao tamanho desta, seguido por outro tipo de conteúdo logo abaixo.

Eu estou a procura de algo como no exemplo destes sites abaixo:

- http://khanacademy.org
- http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-creative

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português @BrunoSilvadeMoraes ! Ao fazer perguntas no Stack Overflow por favor faça acompanhar algum excerto de código relevante juntamente com a sua pergunta para ajudar os outros membros a recriar o seu problema, ou pelo menos aquilo que você já tentou. Você pode visitar também a página [Como Perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: "Tamanho" seria só a largura ou a altura também? Se for só a largura, basta usar a classe `container-fluid`: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container

Comment: Queria a altura também, como nos sites que eu citei.

Answer (score 3):

Isto pode ser feito utilizando a unidade `vh`, adicionando `height: 100vh;` à class que queiras com que o seu tamanho seja automaticamente ajustado de maneira a ficar a 100% do tamanho atual da tela, em qualquer dispositivo ou resolução.

Com `vh/vw`, podemos modificar o tamanho de elementos para serem relativos ao tamanho do viewport (janela). Então ao adicionarmos `height: 100vh` irá fazer com que um elemento ocupe por completo toda a altura da janela de exibição.

Eis um exemplo:

```css
section {height: 100vh;}

/* Seccões */
#screen1 {background: #43b29d;}
#screen2 {background: #efc94d;}
#screen3 {background: #e1793d;}
```

```html
<section id="screen1"></section>
<section id="screen2"></section>
<section id="screen3"></section>
```

Podes também testar isso neste <kbd>[**Exemplo no JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3o2wccfn/)</kbd>  e arrastar a janela do `resultado` para poderes ver que a `section/div` se adapta a qualquer tipo de resolução.
Podes ler mais sobre a unidade `vh` em - [*Sizing with `vw` and `vh` units*](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/vm-vh-units)